# Adding semantic highlighting to comments in CEditor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to extend CDT CEditor for adding formal verification specifications for C code. Formal Verification specification is added as comments in C file. So I want to perform semantic highlighting of comments in CEditor.

Can anyone help me how can I proceed to implement semantic highlighting for CEditor? Most of the functions related to semantic highlighting in CEditor are either private or protected. I am not sure what is the best approach to add this functionality. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg20806.html
Mike Kucera's response here may be useful for you (in terms of where to start), if you didn't come across it already.

> If all you need to do is highlight some new keywords then start by creating an implementation of ICLanguageKeywords. Then extend the GCCLangauge class and override the getAdapter method to return your implementation. Then register your subclass of GCCLanguage with the ILanguage extension point. Then to see the changes open the Language Mappings preference page and map the C content type to your language. With this approach you will get the highlighting but the parser will still treat the keywords as identifiers. If you want the parser to ignore the keywords as well then also override getScannerExtensionConfiguration and have it return a scanner config that has an empty macro defined for each keyword.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But, I don't want to highlight some keyword, I have already implemented syntax highlighting. I want to add functionality for example: highlighting a local variable differently than global variable.